# Seaborn: Passing column name as Label in a function

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have function to plot column from a data frame as below. How do I define Labels for the plot so that everytime I call this function, "COLUMN_NAME" will be the column of dataframe.

```
def plotting(df,column):
    x_15 = pd.DataFrame({'COUNT':[len(df),df[column].sum()], 'LABEL':['TOTAL RECORDS','COLUMN_NAME']})
    plt.figure(figsize=(4,6))
    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
    plt.title('NO. OF RECORDS FOR "COLUMN NAME"')
    ax = sns.barplot(x="LABEL",y="COUNT", data=x_15)
    ssa.annotate(ax, message = 'Count',location='Middle', fontsize = 15)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: `LABEL':['TOTAL RECORDS', column]`?

Comment: Also, `plt.title('NO. OF RECORDS FOR "{}"'.format(column))`